# How do I count up in javascript on each click?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple flashcard program in javascript. Currently I'm counting questions by adding a number inside the array. Is there a javascript way to automate this?

```js
var myArray = [
  "Q: What's my name? <div id=number>1</id>", 'A: Heck no.',
  'Q: My age? <div id=number>2</id>', "A: Cool kids don't say.",
  'Q: Fave rocker? <div id=number>3</id>', 'A: Paul Gilbert'
];
var myIndex = 1;
var flashcardFront = document.getElementById('flashcardFront');

flashcardFront.innerHTML = myArray[0];

function flashCards() {
  flashcardFront.innerHTML = myArray[myIndex];
  myIndex = (myIndex + 1) % (myArray.length);
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <a id="flashcardFront" href="#" onclick="flashCards();"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: myIndex++ should do the trick.

Comment: @GaijinJim That won't wrap around to 0 when it gets to the end.

Comment: Your code is fine, it's exactly how I would write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the `<div id="number" />` tag you can generate it with a simple calculation, first note that inside your array a question is on an even spot so based on that you can get the number of question from `myIndex` with `myIndex / 2 + 1`

```js
var myArray = [
  "Q: What's my name?", 'A: Heck no.',
  'Q: My age?', "A: Cool kids don't say.",
  'Q: Fave rocker?', 'A: Paul Gilbert'
];
var myIndex = 0;

function renderQuestion(index) {
  // render number if index is even
  var str = myArray[index]
  if (index % 2 == 0) {
    str += '<br><span class="question-number">' + (index / 2 + 1) + '</span>'
  }
  return str
}

function flashCards() {
  var flashcardFront = document.getElementById('flashcardFront');
  flashcardFront.innerHTML = renderQuestion(myIndex);
  myIndex = (myIndex + 1) % (myArray.length);
}

flashCards()
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <a id="flashcardFront" href="#" onclick="flashCards();"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Now on to how to figuring out how to get the user to input the questions and answers to generate their own flashcards!

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to wrap around and start the questions over, you can add an if statement to check if `myIndex >= myArray.length`after you increment it. The code snippet below will do just that :-)

```js
var myArray = [
  "Q: What's my name? <div id=number>1</id>", 'A: Heck no.',
  'Q: My age? <div id=number>2</id>', "A: Cool kids don't say.",
  'Q: Fave rocker? <div id=number>3</id>', 'A: Paul Gilbert'
];
var myIndex = 1;
var flashcardFront = document.getElementById('flashcardFront');

flashcardFront.innerHTML = myArray[0];

function flashCards() {
  flashcardFront.innerHTML = myArray[myIndex];
  myIndex++;

  //check if myIndex is still less than myArray.length
  if (myIndex >= myArray.length) {
    myIndex = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="card">
  <a id="flashcardFront" href="#" onclick="flashCards();"></a>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any use for the array. If you don't need it I would just fix your problem by using the increment operator for JavaScript. `++`

For instance:

```
var myIndex = 1;
var flashcardFront = document.getElementById('flashcardFront');

flashcardFront.innerHTML = myIndex; 

function flashCards() {
    myIndex++;
    flashcardFront.innerHTML = myIndex;
}
```

Comment: The array is the list of questions and answers for the flashcards. I want to add a counter so the user knows what card they are on. I'm just trying to add a number to the cards.

Comment: `++` won't wrap around to `0` when you reach the end.